# Vagrant ssh config fault

Tags: ssh, centos7, vagrant

Good afternoon. There was a need to configure SSH access from an external network to a virtual machine in Vagrant (VirtualBox, CentOS/7). I made a mistake somewhere and lost the ability to connect to a virtual machine without taking a snapshot.

Is it possible to somehow restore access to the virtual machine, or do I need to completely re-create (an extremely undesirable event)?